# To change table schema in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, schema, databricks, alter, drop

Is there any way to change data type inside struct column in a table?

Example:

```
emp_details: struct
  emp_id: integer
  emp_name: string
```

If `emp_details` is a column in a table which is of strict type and inside it `emp_id` and `emp_name` is present and I want to change `emp_id` to string.

Comment: what is the file format is used for this table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You should explicitly cast the column and build the new `emp_details` using the casted column. Once you create the desired dataframe you can overwrite the table in Databricks to store it with the desired schema.

This should look something like this:

```
# For code readability, let's first create the correct casted column
original_df_with_casted_column_df = original_df.withColumn("casted_emp_id", col("emp_details.emp_id").cast("string"))
# We generate the new struct field using the original emp_name column and the newly created column after renaming it.
final_df = original_df.select(struct(col("casted_emp_id").alias("emp_id"), col("emp_name")).alias("emp_details"))
```